# PC Keeps Going To Windows Recovery

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, partitioning

Every time I boot my dads PC up and start Windows 7 it goes to the recovery screen. I have tried CHKDSK in the recovery prompt and it still does boot to the recovery screen. The PC is an Emachine (I don't know the model number) and has the original Windows 7 Home Premium installed with no other OS on it. This happened after I added more storage to the PC (had Windows 10 installed but removed it) by booting Linux from a flash drive and using gparted to allocate the empty space from 10 and add it to 7. (I had also found a lot of malware on it when I used Malwarebytes but didn't quarantine the malware in case of it has anything do do with it)

Comment: Are you able to boot into Safe Mode?

Comment: tried but keeps doing the same thing

Comment: Are you sure you deleted delete a partition that was required?  What you describe would happen if you deleted the EFI/MBR partition.

Comment: i made sure to delete windows 10 not any other partition

Comment: You will want to repair your BCD in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment due to lack of rep - sounds like the OS might be corrupt, or it could be that your motherboard can't handle the extra storage. Have you tried removing the storage and trying again (assuming the device has 2 HDD slots)

Comment: any way i can repair it without deleting it?

Comment: If you've got a recovery media USB drive/cd then you can try that, otherwise if it's getting stuck on the system restore part then you might be outta luck i'm afraid